# iPhone App Store 'Prepare for Upload' forever

Tags: iphone, upload, app-store, certificate-revocation

I added two applications to my iTunes Connect account 10 days ago or so. One was a 'light' version, the other I'll charge for. The full version is already on the app store, but the status of the free version hasn't gotten any further than 'Prepare for Upload'. In ten days! There must be something wrong, right? If so - how can I find out what's up?

I did fiddle around with my certificates, since I had created some for `com.company.FreeApp` and then revoked that and created a `com.company.*`, but I'm not sure exactly in what order I added the app, etc. Could that be causing the app to stop in the 'Prepare for Upload' state? Any other ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Have you uploaded your app via Xcode or Application Loader?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Gaaahh! You click your application in iTunes Connect, then on "view details", then you'll find a button in there (top right) saying something like "I'm ready to upload" (didn't notice it before, but must have on the other app). Click it and go ahead and upload. Gaaaaaaaaaah 2!

Comment: voted up for showing that it is not only me doing these things ;)

Comment: Hihi, I even went so far as to erase the first app, which ment I lost the application name. Now I'm one of those underscore guys... ;)

Comment: this is slightly not intuition to me... maybe if the "status" can link to the place to "take action", that will make it more obvious how to perform the action

Comment: apple and their superior UI